# android-How to change fontsize in actionbar items api 8+

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I'm using api 8+ . 
This is my code for making the menus :

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/sortDate"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/sortDate"
    yourapp:showAsAction="never"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/sortPrice"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/sortPrice"
    yourapp:showAsAction="never"/>
```

it shows me the menus but the text size is very large , I want to use my custom typeface and textsize for menus and also supporting api 8+ .

I've found someways but they work on api 11+

How can I do so ?

thanks

Comment: please try code given by @AntiMatter ...

Comment: Have you tried my code cause i have same problem and it solved my problem you should try it

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

Define text size in **dimens** in `res/values/dimens.xml` -

```
<dimen name="actionbar_textsize">TextSize</dimen>
```

Then add this code in `res/values/styles` -

```
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/actionbar_textsize</item>
</style>
```

Then -

```
<item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , I tried you code but I got this error :android:titleTextStyle requires API level 11 (current min is 8)

Comment: I think the only way to solve this problem is to change the API level as I didn't find any other alternative answers to this problem which work with older android versions/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use custom style in style.xml file:

```
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
  <item name="android:textSize">16dip</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use android support [appcompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) lib.This code custom action bar component with appcompat.

`ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        **mActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionview_main);**
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        View mCustomView = mActionBar.getCustomView();
        textViewTitle = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.textView_Title);
        ImageView menuImage = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_menu);
        ImageView userImageView = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_user);`

You create action view xml file then actionbar setcustomview your xml file.